# VBA Code to create hyperlink using cell content

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I have an excel workbook in which the first sheet contains names of the other worksheets in the same workbook.
e.g. Cell A2 has a value "Names"  -- Names is the name of the worksheet

I need to convert the content of A2 cell to a hyperlink which takes me to the "Names" worksheet.

Comment: Why not google? https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/15/excel-insert-hyperlink/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the hyperlink function in column B:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'"&A1&"'!A1",A1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is so helpful to use HYPERLINK function instead creating a macro using VBA.